# Mule ESB IMAP questions

Tags: imap, esb, mule

Currently we need fetch mails from an IMAP server using Mule ESB. Once the mails have been fetched, we only need the attachments and save them on the harddrive. So far so good. Now I got a couple of questions:

1. How do I keep the original name intact using a file:outbound-endpoint?
2. How can I check how many attachments I got?
3. How do save a copy of the mail on the IMAP and local drive?

@1: I tried #header:fileName or #originalFileName or even removing the outputpattern (this results in the filename being "35c7dea0-519a-11e1-b8b2-092b658ae008.dat")

@2: I am trying to make a flow where I check how many attachments there are. If there are less then 1 then I want to save the files and no further process them. If it's more then 1, then save it and process it. I tried COUNT but it didn't work.

@3: am trying to MOVE a message when READ to a back-up folder on the IMAP-server. On top of that I'll save a copy on the local server. Problem is that with the current code, the message does not get marked as read nor moved. The messages stay unread and they get copied (over and over, enldess loop) instead of getting moved to the IMAP back-up folder. When enabling the deleteReadMessages then the loop is broken but the message does not get copied on the IMAP.

Here's the code I am currently using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:imap="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/imap"
           xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
           xmlns:email="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email"
           xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.2/mule.xsd
           http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/3.2/mule-file.xsd
           http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/imap http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/imap/3.2/mule-imap.xsd
           http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email/3.2/mule-email.xsd
           http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/3.2/mule-vm.xsd">

        <imap:connector name="imapConnector" checkFrequency="5000" 
        backupEnabled="true" backupFolder="/home/mark/workspace/Eclipse/RHZ_Project/src/Archive/"
        mailboxFolder="INBOX" moveToFolder="INBOX.Backup" deleteReadMessages="false" 
        defaultProcessMessageAction="SEEN" />
        <expression-transformer name="returnAttachments">
            <return-argument evaluator="attachments-list" expression="*.txt,*.ozb,*.xml" optional="false"/>
        </expression-transformer>

        <flow name="Flow1_IMAP_fetch">
            <imap:inbound-endpoint user="USER" password="PASS" host="IP" 
                         port="143" transformer-refs="returnAttachments" disableTransportTransformer="true"/>               
            <collection-splitter/>          
            <file:outbound-endpoint path="/home/mark/workspace/Eclipse/RHZ_Project/src/Inbox/#[function:datestamp].dat">
                    <expression-transformer>
                        <return-argument expression="payload.inputStream" evaluator="groovy" />
                    </expression-transformer>
            </file:outbound-endpoint>      

        </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) How do I keep the original name intact using a file:outbound-endpoint?

Attachments are javax.activation.DataHandler instances so you should be able to call getName() on them, with an OGNL or Groovy expression. For example:

```
#[groovy:payload.name]
```

Should give you the original attachment name.

> 2) How can I check how many attachments I got?

Before the splitter, use a [choice](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-Choice) router and an condition that checks the size() attribute of the attachment list, like:

```
#[groovy:payload.size()>1]
```

> 3) How do save a copy of the mail on the IMAP and local drive?

I do not know what the issue is here. Maybe marking as seen is not supported. Or maybe the fact that you disable the transport transformer prevents a post-read action to kick in.

By the way, I suggest you leave the default transport transformer as-is and move the returnAttachments transformer after the inbound endpoint, before the splitter.

Comment: Hm... the groovy:payload.name does work in path but does not in outputPattern. It sees it as plain text and thus names the file #[groovy:payload.name] when using file:outbound-endpoint. It works fine in a logger 1 line before the outputPattern.

Comment: Nevermind, got it by putting the filename in a session with message-properties-transform. Still weird the name wouldn't take. Regarding the IMAP mailserver thing, I doubt it. I tried changing the setting as you said, but no luck. The testserver we are using is a Cyrus IMAP v2.3.13 server.

Comment: Ow also a new question, I stored the payload in a session right after the inbound. How do fetch the message from the payload then? The logger shows it but when putting it in a file, it shows the type and such. This is for the error part where I log the original message.

Comment: If you want to store in a file a value that is stored in a property (session or any other scope), you need to use an expression transformer with a single child element configured to use a header expression pointing to the right scoped property (like: SESSION:name). This will replace the current payload with the value of the property and make it available for the outbound file endpoint to write it.

Comment: Yes I had that already, that works :) (I think you missed my follow-up replies). I only need to fix the IMAP issue with moving and fetch the mail message when there's no attachment. Currently I stored the payload in a session. When using a logger I see the message. When using the expression-transformer I can't seem to find the right method to fetch the message from the session payload (or do the same when storing it in the session).

Comment: Why do you say storing in / retrieving from session works then say it doesn't? I'm lost. Please open a new question showing the config with storing in / retrieving the payload from the session and the problem you face with that.